# Using native libraries in command line

Tags: java, command-line

I have created an application in Java that makes use of the JMagick library. I'm using Debian as operating system.

I have the following code:

```
    import magick.*;
    public class HelloWorldApp {
        /**
         * @param args
         * @throws MagickException 
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) throws MagickException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ImageInfo info = new ImageInfo("/home/bram/Downloads/verborgenlagen.jpg");
                MagickImage converter = new MagickImage(info);
                double xRes = converter.getXResolution();
                System.out.println("this is a test");
                System.out.println(xRes);
        }
    }
```

Using Eclipse the application works perfectly, and gives the right output. My goal now is to be able to run the application via the command line.

Compiling it via the command line works like a charm and gives no error:

```
bram@debian:~/workspace/HelloWorldApp/src$ javac -cp /home/bram/Downloads/jmagick-6.6.9.jar HelloWorldApp.java
```

But when I try to run the application via the command line by using the following command:

```
java HelloWorldApp
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: magick/MagickException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: magick.MagickException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
```

Any ideas what could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to supply a classpath with the jar file in when you run it as well as when you compile it. So:

```
java -cp /home/bram/Downloads/jmagick-6.6.9.jar HelloWorldApp
```

should work.

Comment: I have tried that and got the following error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorldApp Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorldApp at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)Could not find the main class:HelloWorldApp. Program will exit

Comment: Yes, I did, it still gives the same error, I have no clue what could be causing this.

Comment: so it looks like jmagick depends on a native library so you might want to try adding -Djava.library.path=<path of the native lib> to the java command.

Comment: I have tried the following command: java -cp /home/bram/Downloads/jmagick-6.6.9.jar -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib HelloWorldApp the libJMagick.so file is located in /usr/lib but I still get the same error

Comment: I searched some more on the web and the following command works: java -cp .:/home/bram/Downloads/jmagick-6.6.9.jar -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib HelloWorldApp Thanks for the help.